# writing click xy coordinates to csv

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have a Form App that saves typed information along with the position clicked on a plot to a CSV. I'm having trouble getting it to output the x/y coordinates of this click input. I can get the full *plot_click* list output
 but this contains commas so is causing difficulty in the CSVs. I have tried every type of reactive expression but can't get anything for *input$plot_click$x* besides NULL

code is below:
UI

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("click on location"),
div(
  textInput("name", "Name", ""),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary")
),
div(plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
    verbatimTextOutput("info")
)))
```

Server

```
fieldsAll <- c("name", "plot_click")
plotx <- c(0,100)
ploty <- c(0,70)
responsesDir <- file.path("responses")
epochTime <- function() {
  as.integer(Sys.time())
}
humanTime <- function() format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%OS")

shinyServer (function(input, output, session) {


   formData <- reactive({
   data <- sapply(fieldsAll, function(x) input[[x]])
data <- c(data, timestamp = epochTime())
data <- t(data)
data
  })
  saveData <- function(data) {
fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                    humanTime(),
                    digest::digest(data))

    write.csv(x = data, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
          row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
  }

  # action to take when submit button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
   saveData(formData())
 })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
plot(plotx, ploty)
  })

 output$info <- renderText({
   paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
 })

  })
```

Any Help would be appreciated!
Conor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there. Slightly modifying your reactive expression gives you the the x co-ordinates.

```
 formData <- reactive({
        data <- sapply(fieldsAll, function(x) unlist(input[[x]][1]))
        data <- c(data, timestamp = epochTime())
        data <- t(data)
        data
      })
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what was needed.

Comment: Could accept the answer if your query has beeen solved?